# How can I adjust the width of a Sharepoint 2013 search display template?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, html, display-template

I'm trying to create a custom display template to display search results in a tabular form with specific metadata attached. I have built the basic table in the item level display template but regardless of what width I specify for the table, there is a chunk of the page that refuses to display as shown below:

[image]

I think this is something to do with the control template being used (currently the default template) I have made a copy of the Default Control template and looked at the code for it but the only Style controls I can find for width break the template if you alter them. How can I increase the width of the seach display area to display more data and take advantage fo this blank space?

Here is the current code for my item template. the control template is the unedited Control_SearchResults template:

```
    <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"> 
<head>
<title>Tabular View</title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the search item in tabular form</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">'Path':'Path','ContractTitleOWSTEXT':'ContractTitleOWSTEXT','CounterPartyNameOWSTEXT':'CounterPartyNameOWSTEXT','CounterPartyCountryOWSTEXT':'CounterPartyCountryOWSTEXT','CommencementDateOWSDATE':'CommencementDateOWSDATE','ContractExpiryDateOWSDATE':'ContractExpiryDateOWSDATE','CSRCommercialOwnerOWSUSER':'CSRCommercialOwnerOWSUSER'</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">P4VEDCT5MJD4-1-327</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">a9eeb37e-6e46-425c-b82f-c011bebf88d9</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://legalcontracts.spdev/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=P4VEDCT5MJD4-1-327, P4VEDCT5MJD4-1-327</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">http://legalcontracts.spdev/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_TabularSearchResults.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_Default">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
            }
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="DefaultItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
                <table cellpadding="4" width="700px">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td><a href=”_#=ctx.CurrentItem.Path=#_”>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.ContractTitleOWSTEXT.replace('string;#','')=#_</a></td>
                        <td>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.CounterPartyNameOWSTEXT=#_</td>
                        <td>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.CounterPartyCountryOWSTEXT=#_</td>
                        <td>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.CommencementDateOWSDATE.format('MM/dd/yyyy')=#_</td>
                        <td>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.ContractExpiryDateOWSDATE.format ('MM/dd/yyyy')=#_</td>
                        <td>_#=ctx.CurrentItem.CSRCommercialOwnerOWSUSER=#_</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>

            </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to the post? It is easier to analyse the error that way.

Comment: try removing the class 'ms-srch-item' from the div above the table.

Comment: Can you please inspect that block in developer tools and check what CSS is applied to it and what CSS file brings that code? And what class is applied?